# properties of the expected value of the Poisson function

Tags: probability, random-variables, alternative-proof, poisson-distribution

*Proposition. If a random variable $X$ with a Poisson distribution, show that:*

*i) $EX^{2}=\lambda E(X+1)$*

*ii) If $ \lambda =1$ then $E(|X-1|)$*.

I have tried to do part $i)$, but I am having trouble concluding.

Since $\frac{d}{dt} M_{X}(t)=E[e^{tx}]=e^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda e^{t}}$, now let;

$E(X^{2})=\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}M_{X}(t)=\lambda\frac{d}{dt}(e^{t}M_{X}(t))=\lambda \left[e^{t}M_{x}(t)+e^{t}\frac{d}{dt}M_{X}(t) \right]=\lambda[e^{t}\left (  M_{X}(t)+\frac{d}{dt}M_{X}(t)    \right)]=\lambda \left[e^{t} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{tk}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda ^{k}}{k!}  +\lambda        \right) \right]$

I would like to get a suggestion or alternative solution

Comment: If you plug $t=0$ into your final equation then you are done.

Comment: Not that I can follow your work: I just observe it gives the desired answer. I would think $M_X(t)=E[e^{t X}]$, not its derivative. Under this definition we get $M_X’’(t)=E[X^2e^{t X}]$, which gives the second moment when $t=0$. Finally, I observe part two seems to not have any question.

Comment: Alternatively you can use that $\mathbb E(X)=Var(X)=\lambda$ and $\mathbb E(X^2)=Var(X^2)+[\mathbb E(X)]^2$. So the equation is $Var(X)+[\mathbb E(X)]^2=\lambda\cdot \mathbb E(X)+\lambda$

Comment: the second part if I did it, I only had the doubt with part $i$, thanks

Comment: Just for completeness: $\mathbb E(|X-1|)=\frac2e$

Comment: Excuse me, I had not realized that I had not written it completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PGF $G_X(t)=Et^X=e^{\lambda(t-1)}$ is easier to analyze: $EX=G_X^\prime(1)=\lambda$ and $EX(X_1)=\lambda^2$, so $EX^2=\lambda(\lambda+1)$ as i) said. For ii) note$$E|X-1|=E(X-1+2\delta_{X0})=\lambda-1+2P(X=0)=\lambda-1+2e^{-\lambda},$$which for $\lambda=1$ is $2/e$ as @callculus said.

Comment: I do not understand why $E(|X-1|)=E(X-1+2\delta_{X_{0}})$

Comment: @Karl Because $X-1-|X-1|=2\delta_{X0}$.

Comment: ok, $|X-1|=X-1-2\delta_{X_{0}}$, 
but I still don't understand why this.

Comment: @Karl What happens if $X=0$? What happens if $X$ is a positive integer? For a Poisson distribution, those are the only two options. (Also, sorry, I meant $|X-1|-(X-1)=2\delta_{X0}$.)

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand very well, why $=2\delta X_{0}$

Comment: @Andrew If $X=0$, $|X-1|-(X-1)=1-(-1)=2=2\delta_{X0}$. For any other value of $X$, $X\ge1$ so $|X-1|-(X-1)=0=2\delta_{X0}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\e}{\operatorname E}$
\begin{align}
\e(X^2) = {} & \sum_{x=0}^\infty x^2 \Pr(X=x) \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{x=0}^\infty x^2 \cdot \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!} \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{x=1}^\infty x^2 \cdot \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!} \\
& \text{This is valid because the} \\
& \text{term thus discarded is 0.} \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{x=1}^\infty x\cdot \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{(x-1)!} = \lambda \sum_{x=1}^\infty x\cdot\frac{\lambda^{x-1}e^{-\lambda}}{(x-1)!} \\
& \ldots\text{and this step would have been} \\
& \qquad\text{incorrect if applied when } x=0. \\[8pt]
= {} & \lambda \sum_{y=0}^\infty (y+1) \frac{\lambda^y e^{-\lambda}}{y!} \\
& \text{where } y = x-1 \\[8pt]
= {} & \lambda \sum_{y=0}^\infty (y+1) \Pr(X=y) \\[8pt]
= {} & \lambda \e(X+1).
\end{align}